# How many calculators should be manufactured in order to maximise the profit the company makes?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

***Question:***

A company finds that the cost of producing $x$ calculators is $C(x)=100+10x+0.01x^2$ dollars. The price for which each calculator can be sold at production level $x$ is $p(x) = 26 -0.1x$ dollars. (The equation for $p(x)$ is called the *demand equation*.) Assuming that all the calculators produced are sold, find the revenue function, $R(x)$. How many calculators should be manufactured in order to maximise the profits the company makes?

***Thinking:***

$R(x) = p(x) - C(x)$, therefore $R(x) = -0.01x^2-10.1x-74$. In order to maximise profits, $R'(x)$ has to be found and set to $0$ to extract $x$, which is the number of calculators.

So, if $R(x)$ is correct, then $R'(x)=-0.02x-10.1$. But, when $R'(x)=0$, $x=-505$.

***Note:***

But I am not sure, if the equation for $R(x)$ is correct and if the method for finding the number of calculators is correct. Also, not sure what a negative answer for $x$ means in this context. Does it mean that $505$ less calculators are to be manufactured in order to maximise the profit, or is $R(x)$ wrong?

***EDIT: (after solution given)***

$R(x)=x\times p(x)$, therefore $R(x)=26x-0.1x^2$. Now, $P(x)=R(x)-C(x)=-0.11x^2+16x-100$. Find $P'(x)$ and get $P'(x)=-0.22x+16$, so $x=\dfrac{16}{0.22}=72.7$.

Comment: The revenue is equal to $p(x)-C(x)$. The company is spending the money for producing the calculators and gaining money from selling them.

Comment: After the edit, you are getting the value of $x$ you want in the end, but you still have not correctly identified the revenue function. Revenue is not the same thing as profit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation for "revenue" is wrong in two ways. [Revenue is the amount of money the company gets from sales](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/revenue.html). If the company makes $10$ calculators,
for example, the price for *each* calculator is $p(10) = 25,$
and the revenue from selling $10$ calculators at that price is
$$ 10 \times 25 = 250.$$

In general, revenue is simply
[(number of units sold) $\times$ (price per unit)](http://www.radford.edu/~wyang/138/application/node2.html).
In terms of your problem statement, the revenue is
$$ R(x) = x \times p(x).$$

Cost should *never* be included in the revenue function.
*After* you have finished computing revenue, then you can subtract cost to find the profit.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Cost: $C(x)=100+10x+0.01x^2$.

Revenue: $R(x)=xp(x)=x(26 -0.1x)$.

Profit:
$\pi (x)=R(x)-C(x).$

Answer: $\pi(400)$ is max.

Comment: How come profit is $\pi(x)$?

Comment: The formulas are: revenue=price*quantity; profit=revenue-cost. In your case, x is quantity and p(x) is price.